# Create .ipynb file from a .py file with Jupytext, without notebook overwritting

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, pycharm, file-watcher, jupytext

I work on **Jupyter notebooks**, but work in a team that **requires the associated `.py` files** to better understand the modifications in the code, through GitLab.

To that end, I ***must only commit the `.py` file.*** On their side, when pulling the remote .py file on pycharm, they must create the associated `.ipynb` copy file, and synchronize them together.

I have creates filewatchers in pycharm so that :

- when saving the `.py` file, it modifies the synchronized `.ipynb`
- when saving the `.ipynb` file, it modifies the synchronized `.py`

**However**, I meet the following issue:

- when I save my notebook, the python file overwrites the notebook I have just modified
- when I save my python file, both files are saved according to the content of the `.py` file

**BUT :**

- when I create a python file from the notebook (and not the notebook from the python file), the filewatchers work as expected

**So I concluded:**

- I feel like when creating a notebook from the python file, the jupytext library is not doing what is wanted, because it might be created to do the opposite (?), and so the notebook is overwritten.

> May I have ***explanation*** on this ?

Comment: "May I have explanation on this ?". I'm not sure this on topic for StackOverflow. You may want to post this as an issue in [the Jupytext GitHub's repo issues pages](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/issues). The way you've asked it here, I don't see it meeting "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development", see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) which is linked about the 'on-topic' discussion from [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: You could also script a bash or Python script that runs the way you want and then make a symbolic link or alias to trigger running your commands in a workflow that matches what you wan. (You can probably link this to the filewatchers, although I am unfamiliar with that.) Anyway the point is although the default is set up to approach this in an opinionated way that isn't suited for your needs, you can customize this to a great degree with a some effort.